# Count is not returning proper count in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called publisher applications where each record is linked to a manager and carries a certain status.

The manager relates to another table called admins which is used so i know the first name of the admin to use in my View.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT p.status
     , a.id
     , a.first_name
     , COUNT(p.status) count 
  FROM admins a 
  JOIN publisher_applications p 
    ON a.id = p.manager 
 GROUP 
    BY a.id
     , p.status
```

What I am trying to do is get the count of how many applications that have a certain status (the statuses range from 1-9 and mean different things) are assigned to each manager.

This query works fine, but is returning way less than what the actual counts should be for a lot of people. I am not sure if there is something with my query or what.

I do know there should be a higher count because i have selected a certain admin id and a certain status and it is in the hundreds.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Here is the SQL fiddle for this particular problem. For some reason it is working on here, but my database has hundreds of rows and the sql query is only returning like 1-10 instead of 126 for example for one of the counts on one admin for a certain status.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81685/1

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. We don't need hundreds of rows. A dozen will probably do.

Comment: That said, it's very odd that you would group by the very thing you're counting!

Comment: Hey I attached the sql fiddle. Please look at my original post and the comment!

Comment: Are you working on Laravel application? Your questions seems not to be related with Laravel, and seems like pure sql question. The Laravel provides eloquent to work with databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (group by every column in Select except aggregates, and use count(*) just in case) :

```
SELECT p.status
 , a.id
 , a.first_name
 , COUNT(*) 
FROM admins a 
JOIN publisher_applications p 
  ON a.id = p.manager 
GROUP BY a.id
 , a.first_name
 , p.status
```

Comment: looking at the sql fiddle the schema and query seem to be in order. Something else is going wrong. Try this: remove count() and replace the Group By clause with "WHERE a.id = blah and p.status = foo" for the group where you expect 126 rows to be returned. See what comes out.